# Is this way of sending e-mails through node insecure?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend, express-session

I know this question might seem stupid, but I'm pretty new to backend and security. On a site that I'm building for a client, I made a form submit an email to himself. Though, to do that, I'm initially using his business email and password to do so. I know this is pretty unprofessional and is raising security questions in my mind. Can someone somehow have access to my entry point .js?
If so, its better to use e-mail API's like mailgun and sendGrid right?

I'm doing something like this:

```
//GMAIL
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: '*****',
    pass: '*****'
  }
}));

app.post("/send", function(req, res) {
    var mailOptions = {
        from: req.body.from, 
        to: "######", 
        subject: 'Client', 
        text: "----Name of the buyer: " + req.body.name + "\n ----E-mail from buyer: " + req.body.from + "\n ----Message body: " + req.body.body
    };
        smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
         if (error) {
             return console.log(error);
         }
         console.log('Sent: ' + info.response);
     });
     res.redirect("/contact");
});
```

Comment: Security is all about your threat model. What are you transporting here that needs to be secured? What risks are you exposed to? Remember that running your own mail server can be easy, but can also be challenging for those that have no experience running one. That's why services like MailGun and SendGrid exist.

Comment: The only thing that I see that needs to be secured is the mail and pw from my client that is located on the entry point .js

Comment: You can make a new account with google and use user and password from that account

Comment: As a general rule, **DO NOT** put credentials in your code. Instead store them in some external configuration file you never, **EVER** check into version control. This also applies to API keys. If someone ever gets access to your code that's very bad, but if they get access to your API keys as well they can ruin your life.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same situation while developing a simple contact form on a blog for a community organization. I found it's a perfect use-case for environment variables.

Not sure what OS you're running on, but you might consider doing something like this from your command line (as a normal system user, not root):

```
$ export CLIENT_EMAIL='thedude@gmail.com' ; export CLIENT_PASS='secr3t_passw0rd'
$ echo $CLIENT_EMAIL
thedude@gmail.com
```

Assuming you're running the node process with the same user with whom you set your environment variables, you can access them in your js code like so[1](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html):

```
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
  service: 'Gmail',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    pass: process.env.CLIENT_PASS
  }
}));
```

I still worried about security a bit using this method, but as long as your machine isn't somehow compromised you're good. The environment variables of a process are only available to the user (euid) running the process.[2](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/14009)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Some deployment systems allow quick and easy setup of environment credentials like this.